# How to handle MySql fields created with the PASSWORD functions after migration to SqlServer

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database-migration, password-encryption

We have a MySql database that has been migrated to SqlServer.  The migration process worked correctly, but there are password fields in the database that were created with the MySql PASSWORD function.

We have tried accessing the field contents using all of the permutations of the SqlServer HASHBYTES function, but nothing works.

We are looking for a way of accessing the password fields without the need for any application code (i.e., directly in SqlServer queries), and also storing new passwords using the same algorithm.

Is this possible?  If not, does anyone have SqlServer function logic that does this?

Comment: This function uses a salt value and isn't even portable between different MySql instances.  You'll probably have to recreate all that data.

Comment: Specifically, from the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password): `PASSWORD() is used by the authentication system in MySQL Server; you should not use it in your own applications.`

Comment: the problem is that it was used a long time ago, and now we have to deal with it.

Comment: If the "password hashes" are 16 hex digits then they're not really a hash but the result of [MySQL 3.23's collider function](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1508/), which wouldn't be too hard to implement as SQLCLR. If they're a `*` followed by 40 hex digits then I believe they're SHA1 hashes.